# Placing text over a rectangle using graphics

Tags: graphics, overlay

I need to add some text to rectangles that I am using as a scale bar. I want the text right above the rectangle and centered. Here's my code:

```
Show[{Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {45, 15}]}, ImageSize -> 48], 
  Graphics[Text[Style["TEXT", 12, "TR", Black, Bold]]]}]
```

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

How can I do that?

Edit: Ideally it should also work if the text is longer than the scale bar, like so:

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {19, 15}], 
  Text[Style["TEXT", 14, "TR", Black, Bold], {10, 22}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 19]
```

The bar crops some of the text:
[image]

Comment: Add coordinates to `Text` like this `Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {45, 15}], 
  Text[Style["TEXT", 12, "TR", Black, Bold], {22, 20}]},
 ImageSize -> 48]`

Comment: That can generate problems if the text is longer than the bar.

Comment: `ImageSize -> Large` or just remove ` ImageSize -> 48` !

Comment: That will mess with the size and the scale bar will show up wrong.

Comment: `Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {19, 15}], 
  Text[Style["TEXT", Tiny, "TR", Black, Bold], {19/2, 18}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 19]`

Comment: And this makes the text... tiny. I need to able to set the font to make it readable.

Answer (score 4):

Add `Scaled`

```
g = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {19, 15}], 
    Text[Style["TEXT", FontSize -> Scaled[.3], "TR", Black, 
      Bold], {19/2, 18}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
Table[Export["fig" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", g, 
  ImageSize -> i], {i, {50, 100, 150}}]
Import["fig50.png"]
Import["fig100.png"]
Import["fig150.png"]
```